# How to use sectionIndexTitles in tableview when pagination is present

Tags: ios, swift

I'm implemented sectionIndex in my tableview That work fine for first page only, after I scroll to down and load all data total alphabets are working.

```
arrIndexSection = ["A","B","C","D", "E", "F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]


enter code here
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return arrIndexSection
    }
```

Please help me if you know something

```
//MARK:- Tableview methods
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionTitles.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contactsWithSections[section].count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MemberDirectoryTableViewCell") as! MemberDirectoryTableViewCell
    let contact = contactsWithSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

//        arrIndexSection =
    func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {

```
    return arrIndexSection
}



extension UILocalizedIndexedCollation {
    //func for partition array in sections
    //func for partition array in sections
    func partitionObjects(array:[AnyObject], collationStringSelector:Selector) -> ([AnyObject], [String]) {
        var unsortedSections = [[AnyObject]]()
        //1. Create a array to hold the data for each section
        for _ in self.sectionTitles {
            unsortedSections.append([]) //appending an empty array
        }
        //2. Put each objects into a section
        for item in array {
            let index:Int = self.section(for: item, collationStringSelector:collationStringSelector)
            unsortedSections[index].append(item)
        }
        //3. sorting the array of each sections
        var sectionTitles = [String]()
        var sections = [AnyObject]()
        for index in 0 ..< unsortedSections.count { if unsortedSections[index].count > 0 {
            sectionTitles.append(self.sectionTitles[index])
            sections.append(self.sortedArray(from: unsortedSections[index], collationStringSelector: collationStringSelector) as AnyObject)
            }
        }
        return (sections, sectionTitles)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Karthik can you explain it more ?. I am assuming you want to print section title as "A","B","C","D", "E", "F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z".  for relevent data ?. What happen after scroll down ?

Comment: may be this following tutorial useful for you https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/indexed-table-view-ios-tutorial-ios11

Comment: sectionIndex is working without pagination. If I add pagination to the tableview SectionIndex is working up to some alphabets.

Comment: SectionIndex is not working without pagination

Comment: @Naresh let us assume contacts page as my tableview. I open contacts page it load first 100 contacts (up to K alphabet) . sectionIndex is working fine up to press on any letter up to K alphabet the remaining letters are not working. If I scroll to bottom it loads the next 100 contacts (assume up to S ) this case sectionIndex work up to S alphabet. Please help me how to handle pagination with Sectionindes

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav . My tableview having the pagination. I want to show correct section when click on any alphabets on SectionIndex

Comment: You have to show using indexPath.row only, Check indexPath.row with count if a present count is less than then you have to load your list.

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav Where can i check the indexpath.row I'm new to this can you explain with example . Please help me

Comment: Can you show you VC code so, I can tell you?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav please check my question just now i edited